# How do I get a gradle property into intellij while debugging?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

I write test automation. I'm using Log4j2 in my gradle project, and I do development with Intellij. My automation runs at the end of a build. And everything that happens when the automation runs is logged using Log4j2. I pass in the properties that Log4j2 needs via the build.gradle file. The config properties that I pass to Log4j2 are the location of the config file, where to put the output log file, and what logging level I want. But when I'm writing tests and running them manually in intellij, it's like I'm short-circuiting the build.gradle file, and I get no properties and no logging when I do. How do I fix that?

Comment: Try enabling Settings(Preferences) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Runner | **Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle** option.

Comment: @Andrey Thanks for the response! But it appears as though I already have that set. I don't remember setting it myself, so I guess that's on by default?